# «El más XX de YY» o «El más XX en YY»

Tags: gramática

A la hora de decir:

> 1. El monte más alto **de** España es el Teide
> 2. El monte más alto **en** España es el Teide

o:

> 1. El mes más corto **del** año es febrero
> 2. El mes más corto **en el** año es febrero

¿Cuál es la opción correcta, usar **de** o **en** en estas frases?

A mí usar **en** me suena incorrecto, pero tampoco estoy totalmente seguro y no consigo encontrar información que me saque de dudas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aunque en ese contexto es más frecuente usar «de», la construcción con «en» también es perfectamente válida. V. el § 45.13i de la «NGLE»: http://ow.ly/WWpy30rueLe.

Fuente: https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1404403782482640901

Answer (score 0):

Segun [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teide)

> El Teide es un volcán situado en la isla española de Tenerife, en Canarias. Cuenta con una altitud oficial de 3715 metros sobre el nivel del mar​ y 7500 metros sobre el lecho oceánico, siendo el pico más alto del país, el de cualquier tierra emergida del océano Atlántico y el tercer mayor volcán de la Tierra desde su base en el lecho oceánico, después del Mauna Kea y el Mauna Loa, ambos en Hawái.

Notamos la frase *siendo el pico más alto del país* no *en el país*

Comment: Exacto, al buscar frases del mismo estilo encuentro cantidad de ejemplos que usan **de** y ninguno que use **en**. ¿Pero hay alguna regla por la que se determine si usar **en** es incorrecto? La cuestión viene de una conversación en la que un nativo español asegura que **en** es correcto, pero sospecho que es un error. (Yo también soy nativo)

Comment: Son ambas correctas. No debe haber ninguna regla que haga incorrecto al “en” porque tienes la libertad de decir ambas cosas. También soy nativo. Poseen una diferencia de sentido leve y hay sin dudas cierta propensión a la primera. La que utiliza “de” indica el todo del cual se considera una parte. El monte es parte de España. La que utiliza “en” indica por supuesto locación, entiende España como lugar. El monte está en España, y de todos los montes que están en España, es el más alto.

Comment: @JoséAngelPérezVelázquez Perfecto, gracias.